# How to use spock to test a service with real transactions in Grails application?

Tags: grails, testing, service, transactions, spock

I am using Grails 2.4.4 and want to apply spock tests in my project.

Below is the **MemberService**:

```
@Transactional
class MemberService {

    def lastMember = null

    def login (userId, password) {

        def member = Member.findByLoginEmail(userId)
        if(!member) return LoginResult.NO_SUCH_MEMBER
        if (member.isLocked) return LoginResult.MEMBER_IS_LOCKED

        log.debug("member.password is [${member.passwd}], input password is [${password}]")

        if (!member.passwd.equals(password)) return LoginResult.PASSWORD_ERROR

        switch(member.validateResult) {
            case "FAILED":
                return LoginResult.VAILDATE_FAILED
            case "WAIT":
                return LoginResult.WAIT_VALIDATE
        }

        member.lasLoginTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
        member.lastLoginPlatform = "WEB"
        member.loginFailCount = 0
        member.save()
        lastMember = member
        return LoginResult.SUCCESS
    }

    enum LoginResult {
        SUCCESS,
        NO_SUCH_MEMBER,
        PASSWORD_ERROR,
        MEMBER_IS_LOCKED,
        VAILDATE_FAILED,
        WAIT_VALIDATE
    }

    enum ValidateResult {
        SUCCESS,
        FAILED,
        WAIT
    }
}
```

**MemberServiceSpec** is as below:

```
@TestFor(MemberService)
@Mock(Member)
class MemberServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def memberService

    def setup() {
        memberService = new MemberService()
    }

    void "test something"() {

        when:
            println "service is ${service}"
            def result = memberService.login("aa@mymail.com", "123456")
            println "result is ${result}"
        then:
            result == MemberService.LoginResult.SUCCESS
    }
}
```

The test result is as below:

```
Testing started at 15:15 ...
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to test
....................................
|Running without daemon...
..........................................
|Compiling 1 source files
.
|Running 2 unit tests...|Running 2 unit tests... 1 of 2
--Output from test something--
1. setup
service is cusine_market.MemberService@54c425b1
Enter MemberService.login----------------userId=[aa@mymail.com]
result is NO_SUCH_MEMBER
Failure:  |
test something(cusine_market.MemberServiceSpec)
 |
Condition not satisfied:
result == MemberService.LoginResult.SUCCESS
|      |
|      false
NO_SUCH_MEMBER
    at cusine_market.MemberServiceSpec.test something(MemberServiceSpec.groovy:32)
Condition not satisfied:

result == MemberService.LoginResult.SUCCESS
|      |
|      false
NO_SUCH_MEMBER

Condition not satisfied:

result == MemberService.LoginResult.SUCCESS
|      |
|      false
NO_SUCH_MEMBER

    at cusine_market.MemberServiceSpec.test something(MemberServiceSpec.groovy:32)

|Completed 1 unit test, 1 failed in 0m 6s
.Tests FAILED
```

I confirm that the user exists in database.

Could anyone tell me why MemberService can not find the user "aa@mymail.com" in database? I also tried the below line

```
    memberService = Mock(MemberService);
```

The result is the same. However, if I run-app, the service does find the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mocking

In your test you're testing `MemberService`, which means **you don't need to mock it**. Just refer to it via `service`.

### Test Data

This looks like unit test, not the integration one. So it doesn't use your database at all.

What you need to do is to create the `Member` instance manually in test. You have it in your `@Mock` annotation, which is good.

Now, create the object, preferably in a `given` block:

```
void "test something"() {
    given:
        new Member(loginEmail: 'aa@mymail.com', password: '123456', ...).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

    when:
        println "service is ${service}"
        def result = service.login("aa@mymail.com", "123456")
        println "result is ${result}"
    then:
        result == MemberService.LoginResult.SUCCESS
}
```

I added `failOnError: true` to make sure the object has actually been created. You - of course - need to provide all required properties in `Member` constructor and make sure the data you provide correspond to the one you provide to `login` method.

Also, you need to ensure the `Member` object is initialized in a way that fulfills the path you want to reach. For example, if you want to reach `LoginResult.SUCCES` state, you need to set `member.isLocked` to `false`, etc.

### BONUS

When you get this test to work, you may want to take a look into [Build Test Data Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data). It makes creating test data - like your `Member` object - much easier.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Happy Spocking! :)